# trying to download object as a json file from spring data to angular 4

Tags: javascript, json, angular, base64, spring-data

i have a backend service in spring data that returns a json object as a base64 , i received this objects in front-end -Angular4- and start decode it to download it on a file

my backend service

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            // Set pretty printing of json
objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(entity);
byte[] data = json.getBytes();
returnedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data);
String fileName = "filename=" + type.getTypeName() + ".json";
headers.add("Content-disposition", "attachment; " + fileName);

return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentLength(returnedString.length()).contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json"))
                .body(returnedString);
```

in Angular 4 i do this

```
  InitDownLoad() {
    this.ShowDownloadSpan = true;
    let url = this._serviceUrls.exportJson + '/' + this.recId + '/' + 1;

    this._serviceCall.downLoad(null, url, true).subscribe((res: any) => {
      let uri = "data:application/json" + ";base64,";
      downloadURI(uri + res._body, "types.json");
      this.ShowDownloadSpan = false;

    });


function
  downloadURI(uri, name) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = name;
  link.href = uri;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

this was worked fine for a long time , suddenly when i try to download the web page crashed and get

This site can’t be reached
The webpage at data:application/json;base64,[object ArrayBuffer] might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

and in url place data:application/json;base64,[object ArrayBuffer]

can any one know why this happen and how i can solve it

Comment: If backend application was started you can try search some error log connected with this action, did you?

Comment: @borino no there is no backend error and the service return the data successfully